# Changing a string array of 0 and 1

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding

I am having string array of only 0s and 1s.Now i want to perform encryption on it in such a way that at a time for ith row of array ,I take 8 characters from that row,parse those 8 characters in base 2 radix and then typecaste it to its corresponding character value.

Function for doing so is as follow :

```
public String[] binaryToText(String[] binary1,int lengthofshares)
{
    String[] encrptedfinally=new String[lengthofshares];
    for(int tt=0;tt<lengthofshares;tt++){
        String ss2="";
        String ss=binary1[tt];
        char mynextChar;

        for(int i = 0; i < ss.length(); i += 8) {
            mynextChar = (char)Integer.parseInt(ss.substring(i, i+8), 2);
            System.out.println();
            ss2 += mynextChar;
        }
        encrptedfinally[tt]=ss2;

    }
return encrptedfinally;

}
```

But strange thing is that it give different and wrong results when i use it in a web application using servlet.What can be the reason for it ?How to get over it.Please help

For string array

```
String[] binary1 = new String[] {"1000011100011111","01100010","01100011",};
```

Output on desktop :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    String[] binary1 = new String[] {"1000011100011111","01100010","01100011",};
    String outt[]=binaryToText(binary1,3);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        System.out.println(outt[i]);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
here is a symbol which am not able to copy,I dont know reason why
b
c
```

The pic of the results is :

[image]

ProcessRequest Method of servlet :

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
       String[] binary1 = new String[] {"1000011100011111","01100010","01100011",};
    String outt[]=binaryToText(binary1,3);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        out.println(outt[i]);
        System.out.println(outt[i]);
    }
    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Output in case of web is only :

```
b
c
```

my decrypt part:

```
  public String[] textToBinary(String[] alpha,int myK){
  String[] ans=new String[myK+3];
  for(int t=0;t<myK;t++){
        String s=alpha[t];
        byte bytes[]=new byte[s.length()];
        char c[]=s.toCharArray();
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            bytes[i]=(byte)c[i];

        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes)
        {
            int val = b;
            for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                val <<= 1;
            }
        }

        ans[t]=binary.toString();

    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by wrong? Do you get errors?

Comment: BTW not related to the problem, but I think it's better to define `lengthofshares` as `lengthofshares = binary1.length;`.

Comment: @mok Not errors actually,When i run the same function in a seperate java class on my desktop and test it for string say "1000011100011111".The results are different,and i want those results that come in desktop one

Comment: @mok yeah ,they are equal undoubtldy.But it doesnt make any difference

Comment: Please test it with this: `String[] binary1 = new String[] {"0110000101100001","01100010","01100011"};` and report the result.

Comment: can you provide a sample input and corresponding outputs for your desktop and servlet app?

Comment: Yes, they are the same, but if a parameter can be derived inside a method, passing it explicitly to the method is both confusing and error prone.

Comment: @mok I edited my post for a example ,Please check this for dekstop output : http://postimg.org/image/ne4f0ezlf/

Comment: @maxx777 i edited the post please do check it

Comment: @mok Though for your string array the answer is aa,b,c in both cases.But different on the string which i used to test

Comment: @user3522121 is this the output on your browser or on your console? and is it reporting any error/warning on your console?

Comment: @maxx777 the pic is the screenshot of output on my console of my desktop java class and in case of web application the output is on browser doing PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); and then out.println(outt[i]);

Comment: so i think it's clear that the problem is that the browser is unable to render the special character. check this if it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669265/how-to-show-unicode-characters-in-ie-using-html

Comment: @maxx777 When i take this result array from one servlet to other by setting attribute of a session and perform some operations the results got changed,So how to take the same array to other servlet in its original form as is calculated by this function

Comment: @maxx777 also if i print this array on my console in case of my web app even then the result is different.Why?

Comment: have you set your content type and character encoding?
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding(java.lang.String)

Comment: the session variable takes `Object` as it parameter. Try to typecast it in required type

Comment: @maxx777 i am using netbeans so it itself do that in processRequest Method,also the result on console for the given input comes to be ?,b,c.What can be the reason ?

Comment: @maxx777 yes,I had set the content type.Let me edit my code for processRequest method

Comment: @maxx777 I edited my post for processRequest method also,setting the contentType doesnt affect the results

Comment: i executed your code on my machine and my console output was slight different
`?▼
b
c`

Comment: I think this question can be closed now.

Answer (score 0):

As I predicted you should get the same result for all the ASKII characters, and the problem is for the other characters and that may vary on browser. So the problem is browser dependent and  as you change the encoding in the web browser it should show you the characters.

Comment: How to change the encoding in the web browser then which is same as that of my desktop one

Comment: @user3522121> Which browser are you using?

Comment: Am using mozilla firefox.Also when i print this array on console in case of my web application even then the results are different.Why ?

Comment: response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: @maxx777 iam using netbeans so it itself do that in processRequest Method,also the result on console for the given input comes to be ?,b,c.What can be the reason ?

Comment: @mok i edited my post for processRequest method also,setting the contentType doesnt affect the results

Comment: @user3522121> Do [this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqI18nProjectEncoding) in the NetBeans

Comment: @mok firstly in my dropdown in properties of project UTF-8 is mentioned,secondly it said to add runtime.encoding=<encoding> in private.properties.I didthat also but no help yet

Comment: @user3522121> Unfortunately I have Eclipse and cannot help you more about NetBeans :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public String[] binaryToText1(String[] binary1, int lengthofshares) {
     String[] encrptedfinally = new String[lengthofshares];
     for (int tt = 0; tt < lengthofshares; tt++) {
         String ss2 = "";
         String ss = binary1[tt];
         String mynextChar;
         ss2 =  new java.math.BigInteger(ss, 2).toString(16);
         encrptedfinally[tt] = ss2;
         }
     return encrptedfinally;
}

String[] binary1 = new String[]{"1000011100011111", "01100010", "01100011",};
String outt[] = binaryToText(binary1, 3);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println(outt[i]);
    out.println("&#x"+outt[i]+";");
 }
```

Comment: why &#x in out.println("&#x"+outt[i]+";");?

Comment: @max777 also,what will be code on decryption side?I edited the post please check if its ok or not?

Comment: "&#x" is used to display unicode characters and it showuld be followed by a semicolon... here 'x' means hexadecimal
dont forget to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: I would definately accept it but please provide code to decrypt to byte arraylist of arraylist.(see post for my update)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly do you want to do in decryption part. Is it converting hex values bact to binary?

Comment: @max777 I dont know about your code.But earlier i want to convert the string obtained back to binary byte array.

Comment: you can use toString(2) to convert back to binary. It would return a string that you can easily contvert to byte array using getBytes(). but be cautious because toString(2) won 't pad zeroes at the beginning.

Comment: so whats the solution?Can i get that byte array?Could you please provide code for what you said?

Comment: @max777 I updated my decryption function,But it does not provide me the same results.Please help.Please help

Comment: @user3522121 why are you making thing complecated? Can't you just use simple and tried cases?